# Pergunta para admin (talvez)

Tags: suporte, pergunta-específica

Eu tive a procurar aqui por resposta a esta pergunta mas nao encontrei e achei que a melhor forma de chegar a um admin seria postando uma pergunta na esperança que algum a visse.

É o seguinte, tenho a conta que estou a utilizar agora para realizar a pergunta, e numa outra pergunta que fiz, um usuario sugeriu-me os chats públicos (que eu desconhecia até a altura). Num destes chats coloquei uma questão e outro usuario me recomendou outro chat mais apropriada para o tema da pergunta. Porém quando tento aceder a esse chat, o meu usuário, apesar de ter o mesmo nome, tem outro id e a reputação é muito mais baixa negando portanto o acesso a esse chat.

Com outros chats que tento aceder corre tudo bem, porém não consigo aceder a esse. Espero que algum moderador veja esta pergunta e me possa ajudar.

Comment: Você tem reputação baixa demais no Stack Overflow (em inglês), por isso não tem acesso às salas de chat de lá. Não sei se entendi bem o que você descreveu, mas parece que é isso.

Comment: À propósito, a segunda pergunta que você fez ficou muito melhor, pois você deu um contexto, explicou o erro e o procedimento que levou a ele, mesmo para quem não conhece matlab já dá um contexto (até dei um voto positivo). Sobre o chat, no caso a sala "[estouro de pilha](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11910/estouro-de-pilha)" é a vinculada ao nosso site (é lá que a pontuação do SOpt vai valer), e de segundas às sextas feiras costuma ter bem mais gente. Aos fins de semana fica vazio mesmo. - Sobre os IDs, realmente são independentes por site, é normal.

Comment: obrigado @Bacco. Entao se percebi bem, existem salas de chat vinculadas ao stackoverflow portugues,outras vinculadas ao ingles entre outras sem relação entre elas? é porque nao existe nenhum chat portugues sobre matlab e to achando muito dificil mesmo arranjar ajuda neste tema

Comment: @Phil realmente é uma coisa mais específica mesmo, eu até dei uma boa lida na sua pergunta mais recente mas não tenho conhecimento suficiente dos arrays de matlab para ajudar. De qualquer forma, sugiro insistir no chat mais um pouco durante a semana, pois a chance de encontrar ajuda é bem maior.

Comment: O que você pode tentar em paralelo à pergunta daqui é se vincular a outro site da rede e tentar lá também, mas ai teria que postar em inglês na grande maioria deles. Não tem problema nenhum ter a mesma pergunta em dois sites diferentes da rede, desde que no escopo e linguagem adequada para cada um.

Comment: Segue link para a relação completa: https://stackexchange.com/sites

Comment: Pelo que sei você pode usar o mesmo usuário para entrar em qualquer chat, eu mesmo entro no chat daqui com a conta do portuguese language.